# Angular RxJS Observable Service is not returning the response without Map Statement

Tags: angular, observable

I am trying to use Observable in my code for getting a list of data objects from the database to populate a dropdown in the user interface.  My initial approach worked every time.  From a Pluralsight video, I tried the second approach to clean up my code but it will not work.  I do not have the knowledge to understand why despite I follow verbatim to the video.

HttpErrorResponse

```html
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:4200/BusinessContinuity/", ok: false, …}
error:
error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:4200/BusinessContinuity/vendor.js:29337:51) at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/BusinessContinuity/polyfills.js:10149:35) at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/BusinessContinuity/vendor.js:87812:33) at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/BusinessContinuity/polyfills.js:10148:40) at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/BusinessContinuity/polyfills.js:9916:51) at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:4200/BusinessContinuity/polyfills.js:10231:38) at invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/BusinessContinuity/polyfills.js:11399:18) at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost:4200/BusinessContinuity/polyfills.js:11436:25)
__proto__: Object
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:4200/BusinessContinuity/"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
url: "http://localhost:4200/BusinessContinuity/"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

Here is my service code: **department.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AppConfigService } from 'app/core/app-config.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { IDepartmentEntity } from 'app/department/shared/models/department-entity';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class DepartmentService {

  private _appConfig: AppConfigService;
  private _appHost = '';
  private _baseUrl = '';


  constructor(private http: HttpClient, appConfig: AppConfigService) {
    this._appConfig = appConfig;
    this._appHost = this._appConfig.getConfig().appHost;
    this._baseUrl = `${ this._appHost }departments`;
  }

  // **Approach #1 - works every single time**
  getDepartmentDataSource(): Observable<IDepartmentEntity[]> {
    return this.http.get<IDepartmentEntity[]>(`${ this._baseUrl }`)
      .pipe(
        map((response: any) => response.result)
      );
  }

  // **Approach #2 - will not work**
  departmentDataSource$ = this.http.get<IDepartmentEntity[]>(this._baseUrl)
    .pipe(
      tap(data => console.log('Departments', JSON.stringify(data)))
    );

}
```

Here is my component code: **department.component.ts (remove some code for brevity)**

```js
import { IDepartmentEntity } from 'app/department/shared/models/department-entity';
import { DepartmentService } from 'app/department/shared/services/department.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'department-locations-list',
  templateUrl: './department-locations-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./department-locations-list.component.css'],
})


export class DepartmentLocationsListComponent implements OnInit {

  pageTitle = 'Department Locations';

   departmentDataSource: IDepartmentEntity[] = [];

  constructor(
    private departmentService: DepartmentService,
    private locationService: LocationService,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    pageTitleService: PageTitleService
  ) {

   pageTitleService.setTitle(this.pageTitle);

  // ******* some code was removed for brevity *******

  // ** Approach #1 - works every single time **
   getDepartmentDataSource() {
     this.departmentService.getDepartmentDataSource()
       .subscribe(result => {
         this.departmentDataSource = result;
       });
   }  

  // ** Approach #2 **
  departmentDataSource$ = this.departmentService.departmentDataSource$
    .map(response => response);

  getLocationDataSource() {
    this.locationService.getLocations()
      .subscribe(result => {
        this.locationDataSource = result;
      });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.departmentLocationsForm = this.fb.group({
      departmentSelect: {},
      locationSelect: {}
    });


    this.getDepartmentDataSource();
    this.getLocationDataSource();
  }

}
```

Here is my HTML **(only show the dropdown logic)**

For approach #2 I substitute the *departmentDataSource* with *the departmentDataSource$ | async*

```html
                <label for="departmentSelect">
                  <span class="aac-bold-text  mx-2">Department</span>
                </label>
                <select class="form-control"
                        id="departmentId"
                        formControlName="departmentSelect">
                  <option *ngFor="let dept of departmentDataSource$ | async"
                          [value]="dept.id">{{ dept.name }}
                  </option>
                </select>
```

Comment: Please try to simplify your code to the minimal expression of your problem.

Comment: Normally, when you received an error `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0.. ` is because you get an html page instead a .json object -e.g. you received a error page because your call it's not valid and you has in your "API" that return an error page-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to everybody for responding to my question.  I figured out why **Approach #2** did not work.  It turned there were 2 problems with my code.

1. my **this._baseUrl** was inside the constructor in the service
2. my response did not have the "result" as mentioned by @Lynx 242 and @Mahaveer.

Solution:

I moved the **this._baseUrl** outside the constructor in the service and add ".result" to my map statement in the component.

```js
export class DepartmentService {

  private _appConfig: AppConfigService;
  private _appHost = '';
  private _baseUrl = 'http://localhost:xxxxx/Departments';


  constructor(private http: HttpClient, appConfig: AppConfigService) {
    // this._appConfig = appConfig;
    // this._appHost = this._appConfig.getConfig().appHost;
    // this._baseUrl = `${ this._appHost }departments`;
  }

  departmentDataSource$ = this.http.get<IDepartmentEntity[]>(this._baseUrl)
    .pipe(
      tap(data => console.log('departmentDataSource$', data))
    );
}
```

**Component**

```js
departmentDataSource$ = this.departmentService.departmentDataSource$
    .map(
      (data: any) => data.result as IDepartmentEntity[]
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

In approach #1 you map `response` to `response.result`. You do this in the pipe of your service.

In approach #2 you map `response` just to `response` in your component. So this map() has basically no effect as it stays the same object. I guess this is the mistake causing the problem.

```
 // ** Approach #2 **
 departmentDataSource$ = this.departmentService.departmentDataSource$
.map(response => response);
```

Try it this way:

```
 // ** Approach #2 **
 departmentDataSource$ = this.departmentService.departmentDataSource$
.map(response => response.result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Subscribing observable in services are never be a good practice so its good that you have modified your code of subscribing it in component.

you should make the below change

```
 departmentDataSource$ = this.departmentService.departmentDataSource$ 
.map(response => response.result);
```